# SqlDependency works with my test Database but not with the real Database

Tags: c#, sql, sqldependency

I'm trying to get `SqlDependency` to work with an existing database and my C# project. I've tested my C# code on a test database and it works as expected. When I try to use the existing database, I don't get an event through to my C# to my OnChange event when a new data entry is added to the database. because it works with my test database, I've isolated the problem down to the existing database.

I've enabled broker:

`ALTER DATABASE [dbName] SET ENABLE_BROKER`

I've created a queue and service:

```
CREATE QUEUE NewEventQueue;
CREATE SERVICE NewEventService ON QUEUE NewEventQueue
```

([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification])

I'm not able to grant permissions because I'm already the same. When I run the following query, it tells me I can't grant, deny or revoke permissions to sa:

`GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO "dbo"`

> (By the way,'SELECT CURRENT_USER' returns the result 'dbo')

When I'm running the C# project and make a subscribe request to the database, under `System Queues` and `System Services`, a thing pops up:
`-dbo.SqlQueryNotificationService`

I've not been able to find any fixes so far, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article answered my question
https://ardalis.com/sqldependency-issue-resolved

I used the following query to set the owner of the database:

select name, suser_sname(owner_sid) from sys.databases

Even though the Owner of the database was set to sa already running the following query resolved the issue:

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::dbNameTO sa;